# How to protect my SDK from being absued with api_key & api_secret?

Tags: android, sdk, api-key, app-secret

Suppose I'm going to create a sdk of my own service. On my experience, most sdks have two things to auth the app which are `api_key` & `api_secret`. As I known, the `api_key` used for identify the app, and the `api_secret` used for access control and verify something what you said is true. Without those two things, you can't use anything of the sdk.

For example if I need to integrate a sdk into my android app, first I should go to the sdk's console website to register my app, and it will give me the key and secret. While I'm using the sdk, generally I need to call a `init` method on `Appliation.onCreate()` passing the api_key and api_secret.

My question is how does such a sdk leverage those two things? I `guess` it works as username & password pair for token exchanging with server by using some protocals like OAuth, and then the other quests just passing the token is enough.

So what should I do if I'm going to create my own sdk, I can't find any articles of that on the internet. Do we already have such things open source? The explanination is also important because I still don't kown how they working. I'm very interested in the theory behind that.

Please notice I don't need any `solution`, I just want to known `how's it working`.

I also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557985/why-use-an-api-key-and-secret) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674445/how-do-api-keys-and-secret-keys-work-would-it-be-secure-if-i-have-to-pass-my-ap) in stackoverflow but they are totally not the same things what I talked.

Comment: Your question is very generic. In the end you are asking `how's it working` but you never define what `it` is. Note that there is no standard how to protect an SDK with backend server, so you have to define which SDK you are talking about.

Comment: My question is how the app_key and app_secret working because I see many sdks use those.

Comment: There is no standard how to do so, so in every SDK those credentials can work different.